# MongoDB: $sum after $lookup array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query and I'm using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup), after this I want to sum the `value` in the array that lookup provides.

**My Query(i'm using mongoose):**

```
  User.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          cpf: "$cpf",      
          phone: "$phone",
          email: "$email",
          birthday: "$birthday"      
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: "$services"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        localField: "_id.phone",
        foreignField: "customer.phone",
        as: "user_detail"
      }  
    },
    { $project: { "user_detail.value": 1 } },
  ])
```

**The result of my query (a sample collection):**

```
{
        "_id": {
            "id": "5bd89899bda5c343749d00f0",
            "name": "marcio",
            "cpf": null,
            "phone": "11999999999",
            "email": "marcio@gmail.com",
            "birthday": "2018-10-30T17:44:57.834Z"
        },
        "user_detail": [
            {
                "value": 50
            },
            {
                "value": 50
            },
            {
                "value": 40
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 50
            },
            {
                "value": 18
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 10
            },
            {
                "value": 120
            },
            {
                "value": 50
            },
            {
                "value": 120
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 25
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 10
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 35
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            },
            {
                "value": 20
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I sum  all that fields of `value` and show that result of this sum with the result of my first $group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation with the array values

```
db.user.aggregate([
  // $group stage
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "schedule",
    "localField": "_id.phone",
    "foreignField": "customer.phone",
    "as": "user_detail"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "total": { "$sum": "$user_detail.value" }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pipeline` inside the `$lookup` aggregation.

```
db.user.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        as: "user_detail",
        let: {user_detail: "$phone"}
        pipeline: [
          {
           // you could use a match on the second collection for example:
            country: 'FR'
          },
          {
            $group:{
              _id: null,
              count: {
                $sum: "$value"
              }
            }
          },
          // More stages to add
        ]
      }  
    },
    // More stages to add
  ])
```